# Store SSIS packages to SQL RED GATE SOURCE CONTROL from SSMS package store

Tags: svn, version-control, ssis, redgate

We have been working on SQL red gate SQL source control.

Is there any way that we can store SSIS packages to Subversion using red gate source control from SSIS package store ?

Awaiting for reply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, SQL Source Control is strictly concerned with turning live databases into scripts and storing them in source control, so it works strictly at the database level. You can still export your SSIS packages and check them into source control using any client, like Tortoise. the only functionality you would lose is "meaningful" diff and merge capabilities.

You can add this as a feature request to Red Gate UserVoice. http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/39019-sql-source-control